# How to use plugman plugins in CLI generated phonegap application

Tags: cordova, mapkit, command-line-interface

I just started with a new Phonegap application and some tests.
I want to use the **MapKit**-Plugin https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit.

I created a new application with `phonegap create Test`.

Next steps:

```
cd Test
phonegap build ios
phonegap build android
plugman --platform android \
    --project . \
    --plugin https://github.com/imhotep/MapKit.git \
    --variable API_KEY="xxxxx"

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/User/Entwicklung/2.0/prototypes/Test/AndroidManifest.xml'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
at Object.fs.openSync (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/glob/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:68:26)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/util/xml-helpers.js:144:27)
at androidPackageName (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/android.js:131:28)
at handlePlugin (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/android.js:41:24)
at Object.module.exports.install (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/android.js:30:9)
at runInstall (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:110:13)
at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:28:17
at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/util/plugins.js:105:31
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to use the path to your android project in "(your_project)/platforms/android/" as the "--project" parameter and not the root path to your phonegap project. :)

The same for your iOS project.